# How can I get Freestyle lines to show around two objects where they intersect each other?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

In this simple example, I have a cube and a sphere. I want Freestyle to show lines around the sphere (or the cube) where the two shapes are intersecting each other.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

[image]
The current set-up.

[image]
The cube and sphere are intersecting.

[image]
The Freestyle lines don't go all the way around the red sphere. How can I make the lines go all the way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Blender does not support that. There has to be a physical edge there. More information (possible workaround) at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52526/freestyle-with-multiple-objects).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the boolean modifier per the link you suggested (as it would work for this project) and a subsurf modifier to get a smooth line. Appreciate it!