# How do I set up freestyle to exclude outer lines?

Tags: freestyle

I have a question about the freestyle tool.
What can I do so I can only see the inner lines, and not the outer lines.
Inner lines means when there is an interaction with a different object. But in a way that there won’t be any outer lines showing.

[image]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52526/freestyle-with-multiple-objects), among others ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it...

The logic is: "Crease" AND NOT "External Contour"

You get the NOT by using the X on the side.

Do you need more explanations about this please tell.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Is your example a single object?

Comment: Yes, it's single object. I merged two cubes with a Boolean Union modifier.