# Fresnel node and get an equidistant shading?

Tags: shader-nodes

Is there a way to use Fresnel node and get an equidistant shading around the silhouette from any angle of rotation? Right now it is darkest at the point closest to the camera. I want it uniformly shaded around the silhouette of the shape.
[image]

Comment: I think not. _Fresnel_ is a function of surface normal and view-vector, so is not inherently related to silhouette at all. Would any of the (post-view-transform) , 2D effects work for you? (Freestyle, Line Art, [compositor methods](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234811/35559)  )

Comment: @RobinBetts Ok. If not Fresnel then is there any other way? I need the silhouette OR the border of a shape (any random shape) colored with a gradient which gradually fades towards inside of the shape.